# Encoding problem

Tags: qgis, dem, error, encoding

I used Google Maps to get a text file with the elevation data from an area. Here it is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7P95aWmH4DURTl1ZWx5VUtVQm8/view?usp=sharing

Then I used QGIS to get a DEM but I got this error:

[image]

I see that it is an encoding problem and I don't know what do I have to do.
Please help me :)

Comment: The error comes from your path `\Users\LOC~1`. What is  LOC~1 ?

Comment: I forgot that... my name is Loïc, is it easy to change my user name on Windows ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Windows

Comment: You can create a new user, without special characters. But you will loose mails, favourites and passwords. So don't delete the old one until you are sure to have migrated everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I saw that this issue is due to my user name on windows which has an accent `Loïc`. I changed it.